# Removing nodes from linked list not working properly

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem with deleting nodes in linked list. This is my code (except for `addElement` function which works fine). I initialize nodes in the list trough input, then call the function which removes the nodes on right side with higher value and then print the modified list, lastly delete the list.
The problem is that with certain inputs my program doesn't work properly.
For example if I input 1,2,3,4,3 then the output should be 1 and 3 (the 2nd three) but my output is only 1.

What could be the problem? Can't seem to figure it out.

Edit 1: Here's the includes.
Edit 2: Included the addElement function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct digits {
  int value;
  digits *next
};

int main() {

  int a, b, c;

  digits *head = NULL, *tale = NULL, *current;
  cout << "How many digits you want in the linked list?" << endl;
  cin >> a;

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    cin >> b;
    current = new digits;
    current->value = b;
    current->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
      head = tale = current;
    else {
      tale->next = current;
      tale = current;
    }
    if (!cin.good()) {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(256, '\n');
      cout << "Input can be int value! You can still input " << (a - i) - 1
           << " digits." << endl;
      continue;
    }
  }

  cout << "Want to add element? Press J if so, otherwise any other key" << endl;
  cin >> add;
  if (add == 'J') {
    cin >> c;
    addElement(&head, c);
  }

  removeElement(head);

  for (current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    cout << current->value << endl;
  current = head;

  while (current != NULL) {
    head = head->next;
    delete current;
    current = head;
  }
}

// function which removes elements which have greater value on right side
void removeElement(struct digits *head) {

  struct digits *current = head;
  struct digits *max = head;
  struct digits *temp;

  while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL) {
    if (current->next->value > max->value) {
      temp = current->next;
      current->next = temp->next;
      free(temp);
    } else {
      current = current->next;
      max = current;
    }
  }
}
void addElement(struct digits **head, int a) {

struct digits *newelem = (struct digits*) malloc(sizeof (struct digits)); 
newelem->value = a;
newelem->next = NULL;
struct digits *temp = *head;
if (*head == NULL) { 
    *head = newelem;
} else {
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newelem;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't mix free & new - delete is the matching call to new

Comment: This is missing all includes. Also, please use a formatter. If you really write `}}` or put `int main()` after the declaration of your `struct`, it will be harder to reason about your code's structure.

Comment: @RawN On the one hand, C++ should be learned on top of `std`. On the other hand, past certain (not too high) level, a C++ developer should understand what `std` does under the hood, and be able to do similar stuff (in less optimised fashion, of course).

Comment: Nope, you need a debugger.  Your code always deletes any number to the right of current which is greater than current->value == 1.  It deletes the 2, it deletes the 3, it deletes the 4, then you have 1 -> 3 so it deletes the 3, just like you told it to do. How would it know 3 < 4 when there is no 4 (because you already deleted it)?

Comment: I'm lazy.  Can you post addElement?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Edited my post, added addElement function

Comment: It appears that you overwrite `tale->next` each time, leaking whatever memory might have been there before. Start by playing computer yourself with small inputs, if that doesn't work, use your debugger.

Comment: @UKMonkey: And for that matter, OP shouldn't mix `new` and `malloc` either.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, will keep them in mind. Saurav Sahu's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets much easier if you can start at the end and work towards the head.

You can't do this directly with a singly-linked list, but you can use recursion.

First, if the list isn't empty, clean out the rest of the list.
Then you see if the node to the right is greater and remove it if it is.
And then you're done.

```
void scrub(digits* link)
{
    if (link != nullptr)
    {
        scrub(link->next);
        if (link->next != nullptr && link->next->value > link->value)
        {
            digits* scrap = link->next;
            link->next = link->next->next;
            delete scrap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, quite concept code, but it gives me a error main.cpp:64:20: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Sorry for double comment. Tried to input this  g++ -std=c++0x *.cpp -o output trough cmd in my .cpp file's dir  but it didn't work.

Comment: @screw4445 It should work with any reasonably C++11-compliant compiler. Use `NULL` if you're having problems.

Comment: Yes, changed C++ standart to c++11 in project properties and it worked, though I will stick to NULL, like it better. Thanks for your solution, it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Why your code won't work:**

Have a close look at this code:

```
while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL) {
    if (current->next->value > max->value) {
      temp = current->next;
      current->next = temp->next;
      free(temp);
    }
```

You are changing `current` but not `max`. Having `max` var in your code seems totally irrelevant.

Actually you never enter into the `else` part of the code, `current` value is always compared with `max` which throughout remains fixed at `1`, and eventually `while` loop finishes when `current` is the last node(value = 3), as `current->next != NULL` fails for last node. So, it fails to get rid of last node. As a result of that, you get:

1(first node) and 3(last node)

---

**Solution: Try this iterative approach:**

```
Node *last, *lastTail = NULL;
current = *head;
int last_val = INT_MAX;
while (current != NULL) {
    if(current->value > last_val) {
        last = current;
        last_val = current->value;
        current = current->next;
        if(lastTail) {
            lastTail->next = current;
        }
        else {
            *head = current;
            lastTail = current;
        }
        delete last;
    }
    else{
        lastTail = current;
        last_val = current->value;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion, but it still outputs 1 when input is 1 2 3 4 3.

Comment: It would be better to traverse through the complete list once and mark the nodes in a to-be-deleted list, then in second traversal, perform the deletion.

Comment: There is one more approach I have added, have a look. It should definitely work. Keep track of lastTail node(non-deleted one) and value of previousNodeValue. In this approach, you don't need to traverse the list twice as well.

Comment: @screw4445 Upvote the answer if you found it helpful.